# The recommended way to register a new user for my android application

Tags: android

i want to register my app users through http.

what i have now is:
1. an activity which asks for user details
2. on click starts an IntentService
3. the IntentService send the details to my server
4. my server returns a user id to the IntentService.

what should i do next: 
should i add the user id to the SharedPreferences while in service?
or should i return the user id to the activity(How?) and then add user id to SharedPreferences?

if i'm doing it all wrong please tell me...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the requirement of application you are developing. Its nothing right or wrong approach in context of the scenario for saving user id in shared preferences.

Answer (score 1):

In my view, it is better to store userID to preferences as soon as you get (in your case it is inside service) than passing it to next activity, unless any validation need to be done inside the other activity before storing the userID.